# Как создать mixin в pug с несколькими дефолтными аргументами?

Tags: pug

```
mixin article(title='Default Title')
```

Примерно так, но с несколькими аргументами,  и у каждого дефолтное значение.

Answer (score 2):

Самый подходящий и красивый вариант - это передать объект и присвоить дефолтные значений при деструктуризации:

```
mixin myMix(options={})
  - const {key = 'Не выбран', car = 'Базовый вариант', driver = 'Имя не указано'} = options

  .card
    h2.card__model= car
    p.card__driver= driver
    p.card__key= key


+myMix()

+myMix({car: 'Logan', key: 'GT6464HG'})
```

Микс оставил по ссылке: https://codepen.io/ilya-lokalin/pen/JjjgEbm